# Learning Python and trying to get first two letters and last two letters of a string

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
# B. both_ends
# Given a string s, return a string made of the first 2
# and the last 2 chars of the original string,
# so 'spring' yields 'spng'. However, if the string length
# is less than 2, return instead the empty string.
def both_ends(s):
  if len(s) <= 2:
    return ""
  else:
    return s[0] + s[1] + s[len(s)-2] + s[len(s-1)]
  # +++your code here+++
  return
```

Unfortunately my program doesn't run. :( I'm sure I'm overlooking something since I'm a newbie with Python.

Here's the error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\google-python-exercises\google-python-exercises\basic\string1.py", line 120, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\google-python-exercises\google-python-exercises\basic\string1.py", line 97, in main
    test(both_ends('spring'), 'spng')
  File "C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\google-python-exercises\google-python-exercises\basic\string1.py", line 44, in both_ends
    return s[0] + s[1] + s[len(s)-2] + s[len(s-1)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Thanks for the help guys. :D

Comment: `"if the string length is less than 2, return instead the empty string."`, and then in your code you have `if len(s) <= 2: return ""`. notice the difference? (<2 vs <=2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the last part:

```
return s[0] + s[1] + s[len(s)-2] + s[len(s)-1]
```

You can think about rewriting it in a more pythonic way:

```
return s[0] + s[1] + s[-2] + s[-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Misplaced parenthesis:

```
return s[0] + s[1] + s[len(s)-2] + s[len(s)-1]
```

By the way:

```
return s[0] + s[1] + s[-2] + s[-1]
```

or

```
return s[:2] + s[-2:]
```

Comment: Turns out this works as well. return s[0] + s[1] + s[-2] + s[-1]

Answer (score 4):

Your immediate problem is `s[len(s-1)]` instead of `s[len(s)-1]` .

You can probably simplify to `s[:2] + s[-2:]` as well.